# D3v4 graph class, trouble adding nodes

Tags: javascript, class, d3.js, graph

I'm working on a javascript graph implementation that I could use as base for faster prototyping.

When I'm running the code, I'm constantly getting this error: `Unexpected value translate(NaN,NaN) parsing transform attribute.`

Here's the bit where I add a node, a [complete CodePen example is available here](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/VGLNLa).

```
var iNode = {'id':4, 'x':111, 'y':222};
wGraph.addNode(iNode);

// ...

function addNode (iNode)
{
  mNodesData.push(iNode);

  wNewNode = mSvg
    .select(".nodes")
    .selectAll(".node")
    .data(mNodesData).enter()
    .append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", graphDragstarted)
      .on("drag", graphDragged)
      .on("end", graphDragended))
    .append("g");

 // Merge new node
  mNodesRef = wNewNode.merge(mNodesRef);

  wNewNode.append("circle")
    .attr("r", mNodeRadius);
};
```

I'm just getting into Javascript (coming from C++) and the way types are defined still puzzles me. When I `console.log(iNode)` for `var iNode = {'id':4, 'x':111, 'y':222};` I'm getting this kind of object :

```
{…}
    id: 4
    vx: NaN
    vy: NaN
    x: NaN
    y: NaN
```

...but If I'm removing the whole graph thing it prints out to :

```
{…}
    id: 4
    x: 111
    y: 222
```

...so my guess is that my `Object` is typed according to its use in the Graph() "*class*" but I can't figure out how to shape it correctly.

Comment: your `mCenterX` and `mCenterY` are `NaN`. If you have empty nodes and link arrays why perform a `.enter()`? Call `updateSimulation()` in `addNode`

Comment: Looks like its working perfectly! I updated [the CodePen](https://codepen.io/mrelemental/pen/VGLNLa). I also added `mSimulation.alphaTarget(1).restart()` in `updateSimulation()` to get the nodes to move immediatly when they're added.

Comment: what is the need for the `g` below the `g.node`?

Comment: It's to create a group in which I'll be able to add all the node's components such as text labels, other shapes, any other object that could be associated with a specific node id. Maybe it's not the way to go, as I said I'm fairly new to javascript, even more to D3. By the way @rioV8 could you write up an official answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some inspection and logging it turns out that `mCenterX` and `mCenterY` are `NaN`.

This has the result that the `d3.forceX` and `d3.forceY` update the position of the node to `NaN`.

@VincentDM found that the `px` in the `width` and `height` attributes where a problem in the parsing of the attributes.
The following would have solved the problem also

```
mSvgWidth  = iTargetElement.attr("width").replace("px","");
mSvgHeight = iTargetElement.attr("height").replace("px","");
```

This will result that the `svg` and `rect` both gets `width` and `height` without unit.

---

It is better to give the first `rect` a class, in case other `rects` are added to the `svg`

```
mSvg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", mSvgWidth)
  .attr("height", mSvgHeight)
  .attr("class", "background");
```

and adjust the CSS

```
rect.background {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #888;
  stroke-width: 2px;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

---

When adding a node to the list the `simulation` was not started again. Adding a call to the function fixed that

```
function addNode (iNode)
{
    // ...
    updateSimulation();
    // ...
}
```

---

Because the initial lists are empty the construction of the link and node `g`s can be simplified

```
  // Create links structure
  mSvg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links");

  mLinksRef = mSvg.select(".links").selectAll(".link");

  // Create nodes structure
  mSvg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll(".node");

  mNodesRef = mSvg.select(".nodes").selectAll(".node");
```

---

If you remove the `g` added to the `g.node` the transformation will be set on the `g.node` and has a result that everything belonging to this node is transformed.

---

Setting an `alphaTarget` of 0.1 for the dragend results that the simulation takes a very long time till it finishes. There seems to be an alternative stop but it takes way to long.

```
  function graphDragended (d) 
  {
    if (!d3.event.active) mSimulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  };
```